# Bound of longest common sub sequence

Tags: python

I need to find the most tight bound (for the worst case) for the recursive Longest common sub sequence problem(only the length of it). I mean complexity bound in terms of m and n, m is the length of string s and n the length of string t. Can anyone help me please?

code is:

```
def lcs_len_v1(s, t): 
    n = len(s)
    m = len(t)
    return lcs_len_rec(s,n,t,m)

def lcs_len_rec(s,size_s,t,size_t):

    if size_s==0 or size_t==0: #if one of the strings is empty
        return 0

    if s[0] == t[0]: #if we find a common char
        return lcs_len_rec(s[1:],len(s[1:]), t[1:],len(t[1:]))+1
    else:
        return max(lcs_len_rec(s,len(s),t[1:],len(t[1:])), lcs_len_rec(s[1:],len(s[1:]),t,len(t)))
```

Comment: I think it is strange that you pass the strings and their length to `lcs_len_rec`. It would be easier to read and less prone to mistakes if you set `size_s, size_t = len(s), len(t)` in the first row of your function and cross out the arguments size_s and size_t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest implementation that I was able to write in Python:

```
def lcs(x, y):
    '''returns the length of longest common subsequence of x and y.
       >>> lcs('abcde','aebd')
       3
    '''
    s_x, s_y = len(x), len(y)
    if s_x>s_y: 
        x, y = y, x
        s_x, s_y = s_y, s_x
    y_previous = s_x*[0]
    for y_char in y:
        left_value = 0
        diagonal_value = 0
        n=0
        for x_char in x:
            up_value = y_previous[n]
            if y_char==x_char:
                left_value = diagonal_value+1
            else:
                if left_value<up_value: 
                    left_value = up_value 
            diagonal_value = up_value
            y_previous[n] = left_value 
            n+=1
    return y_previous[-1]
```

If you want to improve the performance you can compile it with Cython. It runs 90 times faster!

```
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

def lcs(x, y):
    cdef int s_x
    cdef int s_y
    s_x, s_y = len(x), len(y)
    if s_x>s_y: 
        x, y = y, x
        s_x, s_y = s_y, s_x

    cdef int i

    temp_y_previous = s_x*[0]
    cdef int *y_previous
    y_previous = <int *>malloc(s_x*cython.sizeof(int))
    if y_previous is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()
    for i in xrange(s_x):
        y_previous[i] = temp_y_previous[i]

    cdef char *cx
    cx = <char *>malloc(s_x*cython.sizeof(char))
    if cx is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()
    i=0
    for character in x:
        cx[i]=ord(character)
        i+=1

    cdef char *cy
    cy = <char *>malloc(s_y*cython.sizeof(char))
    if cy is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()
    i=0
    for character in y:
        cy[i]=ord(character)
        i+=1

    cdef int k=0
    cdef int left_value
    cdef int diagonal_value
    cdef int n
    cdef str y_char
    cdef str x_char
    while k<s_y:
         left_value = 0
         diagonal_value = 0
         n=0
         while n<s_x:
             if cy[k]==cx[n]:
                 left_value = diagonal_value+1
             else:
                 if left_value<y_previous[n]:
                     left_value = y_previous[n]
             diagonal_value = y_previous[n]
             y_previous[n] = left_value 
             n+=1
         k+=1
    with nogil:
        free(y_previous)
        free(cx)
        free(cy)  
    return y_previous[s_x-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. But I also think it is slow for long strings.

```
def max_common_str_len(s, t):
     if len(s) > len(t):
         return max_common_str_len(t, s)
     for length in range(len(s),0,-1):
         for offset in range(len(s)-length+1):
             if s[offset:offset+length] in t:
                 return length
     else:
         return 0

max_common_str_len('there is a house in new orleans', 'this is a house')
```

**Output**

```
11
```

**Edit**

I also experimented with your code. I think it is slow for medium strings, because your function calls the `lcs_len_rec`-function with the same parameters. Think about cache/memoize it with a decorator:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def lcs_len_rec(###your code###
```

Comment: Your implementation does not work because 
max_common_str_len('there is a house in new orleans', 'this is a house') is 13 :)
The subsequence is "th is a house"

Comment: @PiterD In my eyes a maximum common string is a consecutive string. So my subsequence is actually " is a house" (with leading space). I assumed that is what was asked for.

Comment: Oh yes it if is maximum common STRING then it is correct, I am sorry :)